MAUI error: retain (or strong) attribute on property 'window' does not match property inherited from UIApplicationDelegate
I have a dotnet 8 MAUI IOS app that I am attempting to build and run on a physical IOS device connected to my Mac via a USB. When I run the debugger I am getting the following error:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error : clang exited with code 1: [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error : In file included from /Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/linker-cache/registrar.mm:3: [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error : /Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/linker-cache/registrar.h:257:43: warning: 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'window' does not match the property inherited from 'UIApplicationDelegate' [-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch] [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error :   257 |         @property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow * window; [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error :       |                                                  ^ [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error : /Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/linker-cache/registrar.h:289:43: warning: 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'window' does not match the property inherited from 'UIApplicationDelegate' [-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch] [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error :   289 |         @property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow * window; [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error :       |                                                  ^ [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8303/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1455,3): error : /Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/linker-cache/regist [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
    9 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

The relevant part here I think is
warning: 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'window' does not match the property inherited from 'UIApplicationDelegate' [-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch] [/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]

I googled around a bit and have tried a few things. I changed my AppDelegate file:
using Foundation;
using UIKit; // Add this to resolve UIWindow

namespace TIMS;

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    [Export("window")]
    public override UIWindow? Window { get; set; }

    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}


Adding this part:
[Export("window")]
public override UIWindow? Window { get; set; }

That didn't change anything. Someone on Github also recommended setting MtouchLink in the csproj file to sdkOnly:
<MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>

But this also did not help. I have also made sure to delete the obj and bin folder and try again but that still did not help.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
Upon further testing I am not sure if I was on the right track whatsoever. I have altered my app delegate class to look like this:
using Foundation;

namespace TIMS;

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}


and I still get the same error.
I have research this a bit and my problem seems to be more specifically this:
The attribute on my window property (nonatomic, assign) does not match what UIApplicationDelegate expects (retain or strong). The line @property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow * window; is in an automatically generated Objective-C header file (registrar.h) that is generated during the build process in a Xamarin or .NET MAUI iOS project. It is part of the Objective-C interop code generated by the Xamarin.iOS or .NET MAUI toolchain, which is responsible for marshaling between C# and Objective-C during the build.
So I need to find a way to get my AppDelegate to generate the line @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow * window; instead of @property (nonatomic, assign) UIWindow * window;.

If create a brand new project without any other code, then build and run on a physical IOS device connected to my Mac via a USB. Can it run successfully?

@Jianwei Sun sorry for the delay. I did try doing this. New out of the box MAUI app runs perfectly on simulators. When attempting to build the app on my physical phone the first time it said that it was succesfull and no errors but the app never actual built or ran on my phone. Every subsequent time I have tried running it on the phone I get the exact same error as my above app.


warning: 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'window' does not
match the property inherited from 'UIApplicationDelegate'
[-Wproperty-attribute-mismatch]
[/Users/user/Projects/cds-tims-mobile-client/TIMS.csproj]
but the app never actual built or ran on my phone. Every subsequent time I have tried running it on the phone I get the exact same error
as my above app

You can report your situation on this issue: warning "retain (or strong)' attribute on property ... #10722, or create a new issue for it on MAUI GitHub issue. Let our developers know and deal with it.

I did what you asked; thank you. So it seems unlikely that someone else is going to give me any kind of solution here? Should I just mark your answer as the correct one and direct people who click on this question to my comment in the github issue?

and direct people who click on this question to my comment in the github issue? Yes, of course you can do that.

I encountered this error as well, though I don't remember which version of MAUI I was using at the time. My Mac was running macOS Sequoia, and since Xcode 16 wasn't yet supported by MAUI, I had to use the Xcode 16 beta. However, after updating MAUI to version 8.0.70, I was able to use Xcode 16, and the error disappeared

This worked for me as well thank you for sharing. It seems that most of these issues are largely worked out now between Xcode16 and MAUI.
